# Detecting a word followed by a dot or whitespace using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am using `regex` and `C#` to find occurrences of a particular word  using

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b" + word + @"\b");
```

How can I modify my Regex to only detect the word if it is either preceded with a whitespace, followed with a whitespace or followed with a dot?

Examples:

this.Button.Value - should match
this.value - should match

document.thisButton.Value - should not match

Comment: Please post some examples that should match and those that should not. I suspect you need [`new Regex(string.Format(@"(?<=\s)\b{0}\b(?=\s)|\b{0}\b(?=\.)", word));`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5cs)%5cbword%5cb(%3f%3d%5cs)%7c%5cbword%5cb(%3f%3d%5c.)&i=My+word+here+and%2c+word.)

Comment: So, your search word is "this"? See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5cs)%5cbthis%5cb(%3f%3d%5cs)%7c%5cbthis%5cb(%3f%3d%5c.)&i=this.Button.Value+-+should+match%0d%0athis.value+-+should+match%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0adocument.thisButton.Value+-+should+not+match).

Comment: See [this IDEONE code demo](http://ideone.com/SdRDwt) if you need replacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use lookarounds and alternation to check for the 2 possibilities when a keyword is enclosed with spaces or is just followed with a dot:

```
var line = "this.Button.Value\nthis.value\ndocument.thisButton.Value";
var word = "this";
var rx =new Regex(string.Format(@"(?<=\s)\b{0}\b(?=\s)|\b{0}\b(?=\.)", word));
var result = rx.Replace(line, "NEW_WORD");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/SdRDwt) and a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5Cs)%5Cbthis%5Cb(%3F%3D%5Cs)%7C%5Cbthis%5Cb(%3F%3D%5C.)&i=this.Button.Value%0D%0Athis.value%0D%0Adocument.thisButton.Value&r=NEW_WORD).

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=\s)\bthis\b(?=\s)` - whole word "this" that is preceded with whitespace `(?<=\s)` and that is followed with whitespace `(?=\s)`
- `|` - or
- `\bthis\b(?=\.)` - whole word "this" that is followed with a literal `.` (`(?=\.)`)

Since lookarounds are not consuming characters (the regex index remains where it was) the characters matched with them are not placed in the match value, and are thus untouched during the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"((?<=( \.))" + word + @"\b)" + "|" + @"(\b" + word + @"[ .])");
```

However, note that this could cause trouble if `word` contains characters that have special meanings in Regular Expressions. I'm assuming that `word` contains alpha-numeric characters only.

Comment: dotNET. I tried your solution but the problem is when I try to replace the word, the code replaces also the dot and whitespace:  foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
                {
                    output = text.Replace(match.Value, target);
                }                          so if I have something like `this.Field1.Value` , instead of giving me result `target.Field1.Value` it gived `tagretField1.Value`. How can I only match `this` but only consider it a match if there is a whitespace before it and a dot after?

Comment: @ElenaDBA : That's because they're included in the match. Try my solution.

Comment: @ElenaDBA: So you basically want to replace `X.Field1.Value` with `Y.Field1.Value`, where X and Y are two different strings?

Comment: @ElenaDBA: Updated my answer. See if it works for you now.

Comment: still did not work for me - when replaceing `x.field1.value`, it produces `yfield1.value` instead `y.field1.value`

Comment: @ElenaDBA: Edited again.

Comment: still the same thing as above happens

Answer (score 1):

If i am understanding you correctly:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b" + (word " " || ".") + @"\b");
```

Comment: Still. Run it before posting.

Answer (score 0):

The `(?<=...)` match group checks for preceding and `(?=...)` checks for following, both ***without*** including them in the match.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\s)\b" + word + @"\b|\b" + word + @"\b(?=[\s\.])");
```

**EDIT:** Pattern updated.

**EDIT 2:** Online test: http://ideone.com/RXRQM5

Comment: preceding token is not quantifiable.

Comment: @tchelidze : And in english?

Comment: `(?<= ..` `(?= ..` are preceding tokens, it's illegal to set quantifier (such as `?`,`+` ..) on it.

Comment: Also, it accepts the string ".some" when it shouldn't.

Comment: @dotNET : He says _"**either** if it is preceded with a whitespace..."_. So it would match ".some" but not the dot, only "some".

Comment: Then why it shouldn't match "someone", just the "some" part I mean?

Comment: OP's requirement is that the word should do one of the three things: 1. Preceded by space, 2. followed by space, 3. followed by dot. ".some" (or any other word starting with dot) doesn't seem to match any of the three conditions.

Comment: @dotNET : Updated pattern.

Comment: Visual Vincent. So far in testing it worked except one case - when the word `preceded` by the dot, then it still sees it as a match while it should not, only whitepace in prededence should be a match

Comment: @ElenaDBA : But that should be impossible since my edit?? Let me see what I can do.